# How do I add parentheses to a phone number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have a list of phone numbers which have been automatically extracted from a website that are stored as a string and appear as "xxx-xxx-xxxx", but I need them to appear as "(xxx)xxx-xxxx". I'm trying to add the parentheses using the format function.

I've tried:
`phone = format("(%%%)%%%-%%%%")`
This returns "(%%%)%%%-%%%%".

I've also tried:
`phone = ("(%%%)%%%-%%%%").format`
This returns "<built-in method format of str object at 0x0000024666C96530>".

I'm not sure what symbol I should use to indicate to the program "leave this part of the string as it is," since it's definitely not % or x as I have tried. How can I go about formatting the phone numbers? If I'm totally off on this and should be using something other than the format function feel free to recommend another solution entirely.

Comment: Where is the phone number coming from? Neither of your attempts reference any variables that could potentially contain a phone number. Where are you expecting `format("(%%%)%%%-%%%%")` to *get* the numbers from if you haven't provided any?

Comment: You never use the phone number you have, anywhere, how could you expect the code to find it ?

Comment: The phone numbers are coming from the phone variable. They were extracted from a website using:
```for item in addresssplit:
phone = parse(item,'data-phone="','">')```

Answer (score 3):

A format method requires both a `value` and a `format-style` like

```
print("{:.2f}".format(123.123))  # 123.12
```

---

In you case if could be used like the following, split in 3 parts, then rebuild the result from them

```
phone = "123-456-7899"
phone = "({}){}-{}".format(*phone.split("-"))
print(phone)  # (123)456-7899
```

---

Or a simple regex will do the trick

```
import re

phone = "123-456-7899"
phone = re.sub(r"^(\d+)-", r"(\1)", phone)
print(phone)  # (123)456-7899
```

Comment: Regex method worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately regex is pretty hard to read, and easy to mess up. Therefore, I'd prefer the format solution, but would go for something different to support any number of partitions. `phone = '({}){}'.format(*phone.split('-', 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

This may work if you want a pure Python implementation

```py
def convert_number(number: str) -> str:
    sections = number.split("-")
    return f"({sections[0]}){sections[1]}-{sections[2]}"
```

although as **@azro** said you could also use a Regex.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use the Python `string` module's [`Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) class:

```
from string import Template

phone = '123-456-7890'
template = Template('($_0)$_1-$_2')
d = {f'_{i}': s for i, s in enumerate(phone.split('-'))}

print(template.substitute(d))  # -> (123)456-7890
```

Of course, that would be overkill when you could simply do this:

```
phone = '123-456-7890'
formatted = '({0}){1}-{2}'.format(*phone.split('-'))
print(formatted)  # -> (123)456-7890
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a **f string** for this .

```
string="xxx-xxx-xxxx"
print(f"({string[:3]}){string[4:]}")
```